# How can read input from a txt and write them to another txt file in different threads?

Tags: c++, qt, readfile

I have 2 txt file. One is for reading and the other one is writing. They should be in different threads. How can i write the data i read to another file. Here is my code for reading, queue part can be skip. I dont need it

```
void MyThread::run()  //Reading file from txt with thread1
{

    QFile file("C:/Users/ilknu/Documents/MyThread/deneme.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in (&file);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {

            QString line = in.readLine();
            QStringList list = line.split(QLatin1Char(' '), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
            for(const QString &entry : list)
            {
                double num = entry.toDouble();
                qDebug()<< "im running on worker thread " <<num;
                queue.enqueue(num);


            } // for
        } // while
    } // if

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this? I don't understand what exactly is the issue. You already have a thread reading a file.

Comment: I want to do reading and writing with 2 different threads. In first thread read the data, in other thread write the data. How can i create second thread?

Comment: It will be pretty much the same way you created this thread but instead write to the file instead of reading. This is why I asked, and probably why some other person downvoted.

Comment: void MyThread::Write() {
....
}


I've do it. But when i run it gives me an error. What should be in my main.cpp

Comment: You would most likely need a new thread class named differently from the that reads the file. Also if you get an error and have some code to show someone could help with the  error if you added the exact text of the error message.

Comment: I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

**mythread.cpp**

```
 #include "mythread.h"
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QtCore>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QThread>
    #include <QMutex>
    #include <QQueue>
    #include <QMessageBox>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
    #include <QFileDialog>
    #include <QMainWindow>
    
    
     QFile file("C:/Users/ilknu/Documents/MyThread/deneme.txt");
    
    
    MyThread::MyThread(QObject* parent)
        : QObject(parent)
    
    {
    
    }
    
    MyThread::~MyThread() {
    
    }
    
    
    //void MyThread::writeData()
    //{
    
    
    
    //    emit writingDone();
    //}
    
    
    void MyThread::run()  //Reading file from txt with thread1
    {
    
    
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
            QTextStream in (&file);
            while (!in.atEnd())
            {
    
                QString line = in.readLine();
                QStringList list = line.split(QLatin1Char(' '), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
                for(const QString &entry : list)
                {
                    double num = entry.toDouble();
                    qDebug()<< "im running on worker thread " <<num;
                    queue.enqueue(num);
    
    
                } // for
            } // while
        } // if
    
        file.close();
    }
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
    #include <QMainWindow>
    
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    
        // Initialize the new objects
        myThreadObject = new MyThread();
        myQThread = new QThread();
    
        // Move to new thread
        myThreadObject->moveToThread(myQThread);
    
        // connect signal and slots
        //connect(this, &MainWindow::startWriting, myThreadObject, &MyThread::writeData);
        //connect(myThreadObject, &MyThread::writingDone, this, &MainWindow::writingDoneByThread);
    
        // Start the new thread
        myQThread->start();
    }
**main.cpp**

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <mainwindow.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyThread mThread;
    mThread.


    qDebug() << "im running on gui thread " << a.thread()->currentThreadId();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mythread.h**

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H
#include <QtCore>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
class MyThread: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread(QObject* parent =nullptr);
    ~MyThread();
    void run();

signals:
    //void writingDone();

public slots:
    //  void writeData();
    //  void run();


private:
    QQueue<double> queue;
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QThread>
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QQueue>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyThread* myThreadObject;
    QThread* myQThread;


signals:
    // void startWriting();

public slots:
//   void writingDoneByThread();


};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

it gives 2 error

1. error: 'class MyThread' has no member named 'QMessageLogger'
   2):-1: error: [Makefile.Release:863: release/main.o] Error 1